# Can get variable to set on javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, livechat

Trying to make a variable `__lc.group` dynamic so that the group number is set based on the URL of the page, this is the code I have tried but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Not sure why it wouldn't be working. This is to dynamically set the group variable for a live chat function on site so I can set different operators for differnet pages of the site.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("netball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 1;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("football") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 5;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("basketball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 2;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("social") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 3;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("fitness") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 6;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("softball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("volleyball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("dodgeball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("american") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ultimate") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
```

Full code of script is:

```
<!-- Start of LiveChat (www.livechatinc.com) code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var __lc = {};
__lc.license = XXXXX;
if(window.location.href.indexOf("netball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 1;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("football") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 5;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("basketball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 2;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("social") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 3;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("fitness") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 6;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("softball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("volleyball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("dodgeball") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("american") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ultimate") > -1) {
       __lc.group = 4;
    }

(function() {
  var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
  lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- End of LiveChat code -->
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but it doesn't seem to have worked"? Do you get any errors? Do you define the `__lc` variable before using it?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the complete code. At the moment it isn't changing the group variable:

http://www.livechatinc.com/kb/livechat-for-multiple-websites/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a working, and more elegant way to handle the checking. It defines an object with the names and corresponding numbers, then iterates over it and compares to the url. 
https://jsfiddle.net/gb2tr4a9/

```
__lc = {license:123456789}
var categories = {
    netball:4 ,
    football:5,
    basketball:2,
    fiddle:99
}
for (var c in categories) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(c) != -1) {
       __lc.group = categories[c]; 
       break;
    }
}    
console.log(__lc);
```

the response is an object where `{group=99}`

Comment: +1 Although a `break` when the match is found would be the finishing touch (performance wise, but also just in case there's an order, such as left-foot-football:6 football:5 would always overwrite with the latter)

Comment: Thanks very much for that more elegant way of doing things, I am still trying to learn the basics, I'm still slightly struggling to work this into the original code provided by live chat (mentioned within the original post).

Would I just slot that in under the lc.liscence and that wouldnt affect that variable?

http://www.livechatinc.com/kb/livechat-for-multiple-websites/

Comment: Also, when I go that JSfiddle and click run its not actually displaying anything for me in the console.log

Comment: Correct, as long as you add stuff after the __lc = {} the different properties of the object gets stored. You can declare the object as my updated answer, but its strange that you get no output from the example, its vanilla JS and should work everywher. Im running Firefox 40.0.2